# Insert PHP array into JavaScript variable with key value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

First, sorry if my problem is duplicated but I really try a lot of things but with no result.
Second, my problem is that after using "json_encode($php_array)" and insert it into a js variable the output is "[object Object]" and it is not the $php_array.

**Using key with the array (Bad result)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some functions here
<?php
    $php_array = array('name'=>'joe','10','cat');
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
alert(javascript_array); // Output is: [object Object]
</script
```

**Without using key (Good result)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Some functions here
<?php
    $php_array = array('joe','10','cat');
    $js_array = json_encode($php_array);
    echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
alert(javascript_array); // Output is: abc,def,ghi
</script
```

I expect the output of **[{"name":"joe","cat"}]**, but the output is **[object Object]**

Comment: Your code works fine. `[object Object]` is just how javascript prints objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the javascript `alert()` function isn't very clever - it knows how to output arrays nicely, but with objects it just gives up and says "it's an object!".

You can make a nice pretty respresentation of the object like this:

```
const prettyOutput = JSON.stringify(javascript_array, null, 4); //use indentation of 4 spaces
alert(prettyOutput);
```